# Vue props become null?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got this component in my vue.js app:

```
export default {
    props: ['forums'],

    methods: {
        increment(forum, index) {
            ForumService.increment(forum)
                .then(() => {
                    this.forums.splice(index -1, 2, this.forums[index], this.forums[index -1]);
                });
        },
    }
}
```

But when I try to increment:

```
<i class="material-icons" @click="increment(forum)">&#xE316;</i>
```

The prop `forums` becomes null (I can see that in my vue devtools). How can I fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't mutate a `prop` directly, instead you should create a local copy and altar that instead. Also, you you don't seem to be passing in the `index`.

Comment: @craig_h Thanks for your reply. Could you please give an example? (I've added the index thanks for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what you are doing, but you will need to make a copy of your `prop` locally, which can be done inside the `created` hook, you can then use the local variable instead:

```
export default {
 props: ['forums'],
  created() {
    this.localForums = this.forums;  // Copy prop to local variable
  },
  methods: {
    increment(forum, index) {
      ForumService.increment(forum)
        .then(() => {
          this.localForums.splice(index - 1, 2, this.localForums[index], this.localForums[index - 1]);
        });
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      localForums: []
    }
  }
}
```

You can then call your method like so:

```
<i class="material-icons" @click="increment(forum, 1)">&#xE316;</i>
```

I've created a JSFiddle to show you how that works, obviously I have no idea what  `ForumService.increment(forum)` does (or what `forum` is), so I've just mocked that and returned a `promise` to show that you aren't experiencing any scope issues:

https://jsfiddle.net/wu6ad78m/